# Mysql show duplicates 2 columns

Tags: mysql, duplicates

Table structure:

```
Locations: id, name, city
```

I want to select all the duplicates by name AND city, since multiple locations can exist with same name in each city.

Comment: What have you tried so far? A duplicate means both name and city are identical?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select name, city
from locations
group by name, city
having count(*) >= 2
```